# how to save date in sqlite data base in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i know how to insert a data in table 
       i try many time this on different application it work perfect but .When i create new database and table. when i calling add button then i get error on console this Save Error:

> no such table: bit

and this is my sqlite code

```
#import "untitled.h"
#import<sqlite3.h>
#define DATABASE_NAME @"hello.sqlite"

@implementation untitled
@synthesize enter;


- (NSString *) getDBPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"*****##:%@",documentsDir);
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
}

- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    //Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    NSLog(@"*****:%@",dbPath);
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 

    if(!success) {

        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success) 
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }


}

-(void)Add
{
    NSString *filePath = [self getDBPath];
    NSLog(@"this check:%@",filePath);
    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "insert into bit(Title) VALUES (?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {


            sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [enter.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);



        }
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
            NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Record added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert = nil;

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}

-(IBAction)sumit{

    [self Add];


}
```

Comment: We can save date in SQLITE. But it is better to save as String

Comment: at which point do you create your "bit" table. Can you post the create statement for the "bit" table?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to declare

```
static sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;
```

in the above of @implementation className.

Add

```
+ (void) finalizeStatements 
{ 
if (database) sqlite3_close(database); 
if (addStmt) sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);`
}
```

then in ADD() you have to add the following statement inside if block

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [Title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sql statement "insert into bit (title) VALUES (?)" and the output "No such table: bit", you can guess that the table is not defined anywhere in your code yet. You have to create the table before trying to insert the data.

Just a suggestion, why not use Core Data? Create a new project that uses the Core Data template, you'll see the sample code on creating the app with Core Data.